# Chromecast device is not found while developing android app but it is showing in Youtube, Netflix

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

I am working with chromecast in android in initial step.
 I am following this link https://developers.google.com/cast/cast_2nd-screen_app_tutorial. And try to run the app.
My app run successfully but the problem is that chromecast device is not showing. I have checked  that it is showing in the youtube with the cast option. But I am unable to get the Device in the app. I am working on sender side...

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?? Am I missing some thing.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that in the setup app, you [x] send your serial # to Google.  You can check this using Chrome by  `chromecast IP`:9222

Comment: Thanks for the Rply sir.....
I am working on sender app. Is it neccessary to whitelist my device?? if I whitelist my device what the url would be??

Comment: While setting chromecast I have Enabled the "Send this chromecast's serial number when checking for updates.." I also try Reboot Chromecast...but still not discovering the device in my app.... @Les Vogel-Google DevR

Comment: developers.google.com/cast/whitelisting  -- It is very nescessary to whitelist your device to write code.